# Autocomplete with min Length angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using in my application angular.js and html. So, I would like to autocomplete a textbox,but only when the length of the field "UserSearch"  is greater than 3.

MY HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input data-ng-model="UserSearch"  ng-change="selectSearchType(UserSearch)" list="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name to search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </span>
        <datalist id="{{test}}">
            <option data-ng-repeat=" user in AllUser" value="{{user.name}}">
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY JS

```
$scope.test = "";

$scope.selectSearchType = function (UserSearch) {

    if (UserSearch.length > 3) {
        $scope.test = "title";

        $http.get("/api/getAllUser?SearchUser=" + UserSearch).success(function (data) {
            $scope.AllUser = data;                    
        })
    }
    else {
        $scope.test = "";
    }
}
```

I still have the same problem.. When i type a name in the field, two names appears in the datalist, but when I click on the triangle on the top of the texbox, all data appears... What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: It's not obvious from the content of the question what you want in an answer. Are you missing the part where it displays an autocomplete, and currently your code is just pulling data that would be relevant to an autocomplete when min length > 3?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the HTML5 datalist, then in essence you're rolling your own autocomplete.

What I would recommend, is to create a directive that encapsulates your above code.

So this:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input data-ng-model="UserSearch"  ng-change="selectSearchType(UserSearch)" list="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name to search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </span>
        <datalist id="{{test}}">
            <option data-ng-repeat=" user in AllUser" value="{{user.name}}">
        </datalist>
    </div>
```

Turns into this:

```
<autocomplete 
       search="UserSearch" 
       on-select="selectSearchType"
       min-search="3"
       list="user in AllUser">
</autocomplete>
```

The basic directive looks like this:

```
var app = // get your angular module
app.directive('autocomplete', function () {

     return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            search: "=",
            minSearch: "=",
            list: "=",
            onSelect: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'template/autocomplete-template.html', // use the above template
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('UserSearch', function() {
                if(scope.search.length > scope.minSearch) {
                    // this onSelect function will callback
                    // into your controller
                    scope.onSelect(search);
                }
            });

        }
     }

});
```

You can now call into your controller to make your AJAX call. This callback will allow you to use the component in different places in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rich comments, it's not certain what the problem seems to be. However, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ssqj/1/). It uses `$scope.$watch` to watch for changes in UserSearch, firing a request through `$http` if the text is longer than 3 characters.

```
$scope.$watch('UserSearch', function(UserSearch) {
    if (UserSearch && UserSearch.length > 3) {
        $http.get('/api/getAllUser?SearchUser=' + UserSearch).success(function(users) {
            $scope.AllUser = users;
        }).error(function() {
            $scope.AllUser = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'example'}];  
        });
    }
});
```